# Dudas con java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en el que de 7 ficheros que contienen 1.048.576 filas y columnas hacer varios ficheros:

Orbita42-7columnasNorm22: 1.048576 filas y 7 columnas (sale bien).

Composicion2: resume de cuantas veces salen los casos Euc, Dio y How (sale bien) lo que pasa es que solo analiza 273 casos y no sé por qué.

Diferencias: 1.048.576 filas en las que diga fila a fila si estamos en un caso Euc, Dio o How y en este archivo también tengo problemas.

A la hora de ejecutar el código me da el siguiente error:

> "1.2425816 Exception in thread "main" 1.0 0.90949553 0.7077151
>   0.5749258 0.35534126 0.30860534  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at
>   com.berni.filtromodif.FiltroUnicoModifNorm2.main(FiltroUnicoModifNorm2.java:113)

". En caso de que se refiera a la línea 113 el error dicha línea es la siguiente:

```
dif_euc[i][1]= (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.88126099),2)
+Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)
+Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.090194054),2)
+Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.186721261),2)
+Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-1.080425652),2)
+Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.771797639),2)
+Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.839310604),2));
```

Este caso siempre tiene que dar 0 por si es el origen del problema: Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)

¿Alguien me podría decir por favor:
1) A qué se debe el error?
2) Cómo podría generar los ficheros Composicion2 y Diferencias haciendo el recorrido por las 1,048,576 filas del fichero Orbita42-7columnasNorm22?

Mil gracias de antemano!,

Os adjunto el código, (mil gracias de nuevo):

```
    package com.berni.filtromodif;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FiltroUnicoModifNorm2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int n=1048576;       
        //float datos[][] = new float[n][8];
        float datos[][] = new float[n][7];

        //Definimos nuevas variables:
        int Euc=0;
        int Dio=0;
        int How=0;

        int Euc_total=0;
        int Dio_total=0;
        int How_total=0;

        float dif_euc[][]= new float[n][1];
        float dif_dio[][]= new float[n][1];
        float dif_how[][]= new float[n][1];

        float normaliz[][] = new float[n][7];

        //Scanner sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8;
        Scanner sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8;

        try {
            //sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\ÓrbitasRepetición\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 2\\berni\\f1.txt"));
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f2.txt"));
            sc3 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f3.txt"));
            sc4 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f4.txt"));
            sc5 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f5.txt"));
            sc6 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f6.txt"));
            sc7 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f7.txt"));
            sc8 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\berni\\f8.txt"));

            FileWriter fw;
            fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\TXT Modifica2\\Orbita42-7columnasNorm22.txt"));

            //aquí escribiríamos otro fichero indicando el resultado si es eucrite/diogenite/howardite
            FileWriter fx;
            fx = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\TXT Modifica2\\Composicion2.txt"));

            FileWriter fy;
            fy = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Órbitas Vesta\\HAMO, Ciclo 6, Órbita 4-2\\TXT Modifica2\\Diferencias.txt"));


            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

                //if (sc1.hasNextFloat()) {
                //    datos[i][0] = sc1.nextFloat();
                //}


                if (sc8.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][0] = sc8.nextFloat();
                }


                if (sc2.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][1] = sc2.nextFloat();
                }


                if (sc7.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][2] = sc7.nextFloat();                 
                }


                if (sc3.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][3] = sc3.nextFloat();                 
                }


                if (sc6.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][4] = sc6.nextFloat();                 
                }


                if (sc4.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][5] = sc4.nextFloat();                 
                }


                if (sc5.hasNextFloat()) {
                    datos[i][6] = sc5.nextFloat();                  
                }


                //for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
                    normaliz[i][j]=(datos[i][j]/datos[i][1]);
                    System.out.print(normaliz[i][j] + " ");
                    fw.write(normaliz[i][j] + " ");

                }

                System.out.println();
                fw.write(System.lineSeparator());


               dif_euc[i][1]= (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.88126099),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.090194054),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.186721261),2)
                        +Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-1.080425652),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.771797639),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.839310604),2)); 

               dif_dio[i][1]= (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.721571227),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.086566669),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.04693793),2)
                        +Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-0.734598492),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.425308693),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.537498964),2));

               dif_how[i][1]= (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.843658437),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.088089101),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.09256438),2)
                        +Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-0.737644446),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.405681366),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.487664752),2));

               if (dif_euc[i][1]<dif_dio[i][1]){
                   if (dif_euc[i][1]<dif_how[i][1]){
                        Euc=Euc+1;

                        //fy.write("Euc");
                        //fy.write(System.lineSeparator());
                        }
               }

               else{
                    if(dif_dio[i][1]<dif_euc[i][1]){
                        if(dif_dio[i][1]<dif_how[i][1]){
                            Dio=Dio+1;

                            //fy.write("Dio");
                            //fy.write(System.lineSeparator());

                        }
                            }

                    else{                               
                         if(dif_how[i][1]<dif_euc[i][1]){
                             if(dif_how[i][1]<dif_dio[i][1]){
                                    How=How+1;


                                }
                         }
                            }
                        }

                }

            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

            Euc_total=(Euc*100)/(Euc+Dio+How);
            Dio_total=(Dio*100)/(Euc+Dio+How);
            How_total=(How*100)/(Euc+Dio+How);

            System.out.println(Euc);
            System.out.println(Dio);
            System.out.println(How);

            System.out.println(Euc_total);
            System.out.println(Dio_total);
            System.out.println(How_total);


            fx.write("["+"(Euc_total "+Euc_total+ ") " + "(Euc "+Euc +")"+ "]" + "\t "
                      + "["+"(Dio_total "+Dio_total+ ") " + "(Dio "+Dio +")"+ "]" + "\t "
                      + "["+"(How_total "+How_total+ ") " + "(How "+How +")"+ "]" );
            fx.flush();
            fx.close();

            fy.flush();
            fy.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{
        }       



    }


}
```

Comment: creo que el for debe ser for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){  enfásis en n-1

Comment: No, esa parte está bien. Con `for(int i=0;i<n; i++)` la variable `i` llega a tomar como mucho el valor `n-1`, que es válido para acceder al array como primera dimensión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta línea declaras dif_euc como array de tamaño n en la primera dimensión y 1 en la segunda dimensión :

```
    float dif_euc[][]= new float[n][1];
```

En esta línea accedes al elemento 1 en el segundo índice :

```
    dif_euc[i][1]= (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((normaliz[i][0]-0.88126099),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][1]-1),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][2]-1.090194054),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][3]-1.186721261),2)
                    +Math.pow((normaliz[i][4]-1.080425652),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][5]-0.771797639),2)+Math.pow((normaliz[i][6]-0.839310604),2));
```

Lo cual siempre va a dar una excepción de fuera de límites, porque el segundo índice debe ser menor que el tamaño de la segunda dimensión; que es 1.

No te daría error si usas `dif_euc[i][0]` o si inicializas el array como `new float[n][2]`.

Lo mismo sucede con `dif_dio` y `dif_how`.

Comment: Muchas gracias compadre!! Funciona!!

Comment: Pero aún tengo el problema de que parece que no se recorren las i filas para hacer los archivos Composicion2 y Diferencias haciendo el recorrido por las 1,048,576 filas del fichero Orbita42-7columnasNorm22...sabrías si hay algún problema de por qué no se está haciendo el recorrido?